# Bootstrap Twitter Dropdown: Make the parent follow the link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap twitter dropdown menu. I replaced the click event with hover event.
Now the only problem is  is supposed to follow www.google.com but it doesn't. I tried with:

```
 jQuery(".nav .dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
      return true;
    });
```

but no dice.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>text</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(
        function() {jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();},
        function() {jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();}
      );

        jQuery(".nav .dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
          return true;
        });
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="http://www.google.com">
          Dropdown
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgdwM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really too sure on what you are trying to achieve here.

But this would make the `.click()` take you to google.

```
$(".nav .dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

As for why the `<a>` click event is eaten I am not currently sure.

Comment: Well not really like this, as I need to use dinamically values but I figured out somehow based on your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I assume you just set `window.location = $("#element").href()` or so. Well at least you got it working!

Comment: Just `window.location = this.href` is sufficient.

Answer (score 16):

You can accomplish this with no JavaScript by changing the markup a bit and adding a CSS class.

**Change the HTML markup to (**note** *disabled* is added next to dropdown-toggle):**

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="http://www.google.com">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

**If you want the submenu to appear on hover (since clicking will now go to the specified url), add this CSS class:**

```
.nav li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
{
    display: block;    
}
```

This applies to Bootstrap version 2.3.1.

Comment: Awesome! Your answer should be accepted instead of the one on top. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the parent to follow the link on Wordpress use this:

```
    $(".nav .dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap 3.0 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) say to use the `data-target` attribute to preserve clickable links.

So, your HTML would become:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="http://www.google.com" href="#">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```